# Setting up sub-domains with 123-reg.co.uk

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, virtualhost, subdomain, nameserver

Firstly I'm not sure if this was the right site to post this question, but it seemed more appropriate that using stack-overflow because its Web/DNS based.

I'm having a bit of trouble setting up a sub domain, I have 2 domain names linked to my vps running Ubuntu 10.04 with apache2.2. I'm using virtual hosts to redirect 'mydomain'.co.uk to a sub folder and this is all working fine.

My problem is that I cant seem to link projects.mydomain.com to a folder, the request never seems to get to my webserver.

Now, 123 reg wants £10 per year to register sub domains** witch is ridiculous seeing as a) they should be free and b) my main domains cost me less than that for 2 years. So what I'm asking is it normal to have to pay for sub-domains or is it just 123 reg? If so, if I moved to another provider would I be able and how could I properly point theses sub domains to the correct place?

any suggestions for what to do about this would be grate!

Thanks guys and girls.

- Waltzy

** - Edit.

Turns out the £10 sub domain thing has nothing to do with just wanting to register addresses like this, you can do that by adding an A record to the DNS. After reading this someone at reg123 actually phoned me! Talk about customer support!

Comment: Did you have `NameVirtualHost *:80` in the configuration file?

Comment: Perhaps subdomains in your providers sense is a separate hosting account, with web/ftp etc. Send them an e-mail directly and ask how you can edit your DNS zone.

Comment: What is the £10 charge for as it is unclear if you setup the subdomain just via DNS?

Comment: You're really asking for a _record_ in a zone, rather than a subdomain (which is easily solved as per the answers). It turns out though, even now 9 years after you asked this question that 123reg don't support making subdomains in their DNS (they don't support the NS record you need).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to your 123-reg control panel, in the Domain Names section select thehubworld.co.uk and click Manage. On the manage domain form, under Advanced Domain Settings click Manage DNS ... then Scroll down till you get to the A, CNAME and TXT records form. You can use this to Add New Entry

```
projects A 46.226.248.31
```

Click Update DNS. You should now have a new A record pointing to your IP address that will resolve to `projects.thehubworld.co.uk`. If Your apache is configured correctly then it should now serve pages from your sub domain.

Answer (score 2):

```
eps@gank:~$ host thehubworld.co.uk
thehubworld.co.uk has address 46.226.248.31
eps@gank:~$ host projects.thehubworld.co.uk
Host projects.thehubworld.co.uk not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

You need to add "projects" to your DNS server/provider, either as a A-record directly against the IP or use CNAME against another hostname that points against the IP.

Comment: I found it, thanks for the advice, I set an A record for projects to my IP and it seems to be (nearly) routing properly now. thanks!